# the issue about the "Variable not in scope" and the " Exception: <interactive>: Non-exhaustive patterns in function"

Tags: haskell

I encountered the error "***Variable not in scope: other :: Bool***" when I am running the below codes:

```
unroll x [] = []
unroll 0 y = []
unroll x (y:ys) | x > length (y:ys) = y:unroll x-1 ys | otherwise = take x (y:ys)
```

The result:

```
Prelude>     unroll x [] = []
Prelude>     unroll 0 y = []
Prelude>     unroll x (y:ys) | x > length (y:ys) = y:unroll x-1 ys | otherwise = take x (y:ys)

<interactive>:89:5: error:
    ? Couldn't match type ‘[a] -> [a]’ with ‘[a]’
      Expected type: Int -> [a]
        Actual type: Int -> [a] -> [a]
    ? Relevant bindings include
        unroll :: Int -> [a] (bound at <interactive>:89:5)
Prelude>
```

And another issue, which is "****** Exception: :12:1-72: Non-exhaustive patterns in function subst***" jumped out when I am running the second codes:

```
subst _ _ [] = []
subst "" "" (x:xs) = (x:xs)
subst a b (x:xs) | x == a = b : subst a b xs | x /= a = x : subst a b xs*
```

The result2:

```
Prelude> subst _ _ [] = []
Prelude> subst "" "" (x:xs) = (x:xs)
Prelude> subst a b (x:xs) | x == a = b : subst a b xs | x /= a = x : subst a b xs
Prelude> subst 2 0 [1,2,0,1]
[1,0,0,1*** Exception: <interactive>:92:1-72: Non-exhaustive patterns in function subst
```

Can anyone help me to explain and solve the issue above?

Thank you very much!

Cheers

Comment: @jaroslawj has explained how to fix the first issue. Regarding the second one, I can't see the issue with the code (the patterns look exhaustive to me) - can you show me how you are calling the function when you get the error? And why is there a `*` at the start of the first line of each definition. Are you loading these functions from a file or putting them directly into GHCi? In the latter case, you need `:{` at the start to indicate this is a multi-line definition, and `}:` at the end.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond Sorry, I just copy and paste the codes. The original codes do not have the * symbol. and when I have replaced the other to otherwise, it still reports the error.

Comment: can you please edit the question so that it shows the exact code you're running?

Comment: @Robin Zigmond, I have updated the codes and the results. Thank you very much. I waste one afternoon to seek the reason, but nothing useful. :(

Comment: thanks - so you're trying to put multiline function definitions directly into GHCi, one line at a time. As I already said, that doesn't work - unless you put `:{` before it and `:}` after (each on a line of its own). Or better still, write the function definition (normally) in a `.hs` file then load it into GHCi with `:l`

Comment: also, the particular error it's now showing for `unroll` is because of this: `y:unroll x-1 ys`, you're missing necessary parentheses, it should be `y:(unroll (x-1) ys)`. [Also I would strongly advise to put each guard on a separate line, it's very hard to read when they're all on 1 line.]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try them

Comment: There's almost certainly a duplicate for the `y: unroll x - 1 ys` / `y : unroll (x - 1) ys` issue as well, but I can't find one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example replace `other` with `otherwise`. In second example you don't have a total function, that is defined for all possible values of its input - in particular you are missing function definition for the list with one element `subst a b [x] = -- place function definition here`

Comment: Sorry, after I replaced the other to otherwise, it still reports the error.